# Redirecting certain users to different pages (PHP)

Tags: php, email, redirect, string-comparison

I am trying to redirect registered users who's email address contains a certain string.

example email 1 -> 12345@email.com
example email 2 -> 12345.abc@email.com

I want to separate emails containing `.abc@email.com` and send them to a separate page using a header redirect. This is intended in signing in a user with an email containing `.abc@` to an administration page.

Currently all users are being redirected to the same page regardless of the email address.

Example snippet code below. This is my first time asking a question, I hope I have supplied enough information.

```
$_SESSION["user_id"] = $row[0];
$_SESSION["fname"] = $row[1];
if ($email==".abc@email.com")
{
    header('Location:home.php');
}
else
    header ('Location:home2.php');
}
```

Comment: Where does `$email` come from ?

Comment: $email  = $_POST['email'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cut off your email string, if you want to compare only the last part.

```
$cmp = ".abc@email.com";
if (substr($email, -strlen($cmp)) == $cmp)
{
    header('Location:home.php');
}
else
    header ('Location:home2.php');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should work with regular expression. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Try do it:

```
preg_match("/\.abc@email\.com$/", $email, $result);

if (!count($result))
{
   // Go to .abc@ page
   header('Location:home.php');

 } else
   header ('Location:home2.php');
```

saluti,

Comment: You can use `preg_match` directly: `if (preg_match("/\.abc@email\.com$/", $email))`